Package tikz: Giving up on this path. Did you forget a semicolon?
I'm implementing a Red Black Tree in LaTeX using tikz, and have been stuck on the error message Package tikz: Giving up on this path. Did you forget a semicolon?.
Here's my code thus far
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage{tikz}

\usetikzlibrary{
   shapes.geometric,
   arrows.meta,
   positioning
}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[h]
   \centering
   \begin{tikzpicture}[
      level distance=1.5cm, sibling distance=2.5cm,
      every black node/.style = {circle, draw, minimum size=1.0cm, inner sep=2pt, text centered, fill=black!30},
      every red node/.style = {circle, draw, minimum size=1.0cm, inner sep=2pt, text centered, fill=red!30},
      every nil node/.style = {rectangle, draw=none, minimum size=0.5cm, text centered, font=\scshape, label={center:nill}}
   ]
      \node[every black node] {0}
         child[missing]
         child {
            \node[every red node] {1}
               child[missing]
               child {
                  \node[every black node] {2}
                     child[missing]
                     child {
                        \node[every red node] {3}
                           child[missing]
                           child {
                              \node[every black node] {4}
                                 child[every nil node] {}
                                 child[every nil node] {}
                           }
                     }
               }
         };
   \end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}

\end{document}

I wish not to turn this question into a "find and fix the error for me" sort of thing, but I've tried and researched for much time on questions of the same error and came up empty. Any help is appreciated.

Culprit is use \node in tree structure. It has to be just node:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{
   shapes.geometric,
   arrows.meta,
   positioning
}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[h]
   \centering
   \begin{tikzpicture}[
level distance=1.5cm, sibling distance=2.5cm,
every black node/.style = {circle, draw, minimum size=1.0cm, inner sep=2pt, text centered, fill=black!30},
every red node/.style = {circle, draw, minimum size=1.0cm, inner sep=2pt, text centered, fill=red!30},
every nil node/.style = {rectangle, draw=none, minimum size=0.5cm, text centered, font=\scshape, label={center:nill}}
                        ]
\node[every black node] {0}
    child[missing]
    child {
            node[every red node] {1}    % <---
               child[missing]
               child {
                  node[every black node] {2}    % <---
                     child[missing]
                     child {
                        node[every red node] {3}    % <---
                           child[missing]
                           child {
                           node[every black node] {4}   % <---
                                 child[every nil node] {}
                                 child[every nil node] {}
                           }
                     }
               }
         };
   \end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}

\end{document}


